# Internal server error while updating profile without image

Tags: node.js, cloudinary, internal-server-error

#### I'm getting an internal server error while updating the user profile. It's updated when I update with a new avatar but get an error while updating without **avatar**

*Backend Code*

```
exports.updateProfile = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {

    const newUserData = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
    };

    // clodunary
    if (req.body.avatar !== "") {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    
        const imageId = user.avatar.public_id;
    
        await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(imageId);
    
        const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
          folder: "avatars",
          width: 150,
          crop: "scale",
        });
    
        newUserData.avatar = {
          public_id: myCloud.public_id,
          url: myCloud.secure_url,
        };
      }
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, newUserData, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
    })

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true
    })
});
```

Comment: What's the error you're receiving? And which line of that code triggers the error? Can you share a stacktrace?

Comment: I assume "without avatar" means `req.body.avatar === undefined`. But you check the condition `req.body.avatar !== ""`, which is true even if `req.body.avatar === undefined`, and in this case the `cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload` would fail.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen What may i do if i want to update only username as well? If i comment out the cloudinary code, it work to update name or email individually.

Comment: Try `if (req.body.avatar !== "" && req.body.avatar !== undefined) ...`